# How to produce a new string withotu any leading spaces on the left and right side of the given string in Python?

Tags: python

side of the string or trialing spaces on the right side of the string, based on the second argument.
We are not allowed to use lstrip/rstrip or any built in string methods..

I got the right side down, but I'm struggling with the left. What's wrong with my code?

```
def strip(given: str, direction: str) -> str:
    starting_string: str = ""
    starting_string_2: str = ""
    i: int = 0
    i_2: int = 0
    truth: bool = True
    if direction == "left":
       while i < len(given):
             if i > 0 and given[i] != " " and given[i-1] == " ":
                      ending_point: int = i
                      if i > ending_point:
                         starting_string += given[i]
       return starting_string
     if direction == "right":
          while truth:
                 starting_point = i_2 + 1
                 starting_string_2 += given[i_2]
                 if given[i_2] != " " and given[starting_point] == " ":
                    truth = False
                 i_2 += 1
        return starting_string_2
```

Comment: We aren't allowed to use lstrip :(

Comment: Ah, sorry - I meant we aren't allowed to use strip or any built in string methods.

Comment: I just read it sorry

Answer (score 1):

Trying to retain as much of your code as possible:

```
def strip(given: str, direction: str) -> str:
    starting_string: str = ""
    starting_string_2: str = ""
    i: int = 0
    i_2: int = 0
    truth: bool = True
    ending_point = len(given)  # need to set this
    if direction == "left":
       while i < len(given):
             if i > 0 and given[i] != " " and given[i-1] == " ":
                      ending_point: int = i
             # following line must shifted left to match previous if
             if i >= ending_point:  # use >=, not >
               starting_string += given[i]
             i+=1   #  increment counter else infinite loop
       return starting_string
    if direction == "right":
        while truth:
               starting_point = i_2 + 1
               starting_string_2 += given[i_2]
               if given[i_2] != " " and given[starting_point] == " ":
                  truth = False
               i_2 += 1
        return starting_string_2


s = '    hello    '
print('>' + strip(s,'left') + '<')
print('>' + strip(s,'right') + '<')
print('>' + strip(strip(s,'right'),'left') + '<')
```

Output

```
>hello    <
>    hello<
>hello<
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! If you don't mind, could you provide a brief explanation with your changes? What did I do wrong and why didn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

Use re.split

```
import re
def fun(str_, cond):
...     return {"left": re.split(r"^\s+",cond)[1], "right": re.split(r"\s+$",str_)[0]}.get(cond, "Cond should be left or right")
```